# Calling a Webservice from PHP

Tags: java, php, web-services, wsdl, soap-client

I have been trying to call a webservice created in java from bottom to top approach and want to call it through my PHP file but it always gives me an error.

Code I have tried:

```
$client = new SoapClient("http://localhost:8080/Indexer/services/IndexerService?wsdl");
$params = array(
      'anId' => 3,
      'action' => 'OMNOMNOMNOM',
      'parameters' => array(
                  'Param' => array(
                          array('Name' => 'in0', 'Value' => 'Skinnarlyngen startar Välkommen')
      )
));
$result = $client->__soapCall("getIds",$params);

print_r($result);
```

second piece of code which i tried:

```
$wsdl = 'http://localhost:8080/Indexer/services/IndexerService?wsdl';   
  $client = new SoapClient($wsdl );

  print($client->getIds("ibm"));
```

my webservice is giving perfect results while trying it with java client:

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:soapenc12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding" xmlns:tns="http://labs.aroha.com" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap11="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:wsdlsoap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:soapenc11="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" targetNamespace="http://labs.aroha.com">
<wsdl:types>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" attributeFormDefault="qualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://labs.aroha.com">
<xsd:element name="example">
<xsd:complexType>
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="in0" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
<xsd:element name="exampleResponse">
<xsd:complexType>
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="out" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
</wsdl:types>
<wsdl:message name="exampleRequest">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:example"></wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="exampleResponse">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:exampleResponse"></wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:portType name="IndexerServicePortType">
<wsdl:operation name="example">
<wsdl:input name="exampleRequest" message="tns:exampleRequest"></wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output name="exampleResponse" message="tns:exampleResponse"></wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
<wsdl:binding name="IndexerServiceHttpBinding" type="tns:IndexerServicePortType">
<wsdlsoap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
<wsdl:operation name="example">
<wsdlsoap:operation soapAction=""/>
<wsdl:input name="exampleRequest">
<wsdlsoap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output name="exampleResponse">
<wsdlsoap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:service name="IndexerService">
<wsdl:port name="IndexerServiceHttpPort" binding="tns:IndexerServiceHttpBinding">
<wsdlsoap:address location="http://localhost:8080/Indexer/services/IndexerService"/>
</wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

In every case it has given me following error:

```
Fatal error: SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://localhost:8080/Indexer/services/IndexerService?wsdl' : failed to load external entity
```

Can anyone help me out that how can I call a java written webservice in php code.

I want to mention that I am using php 5 and wamp already enabled soap extension in my php.

Comment: Can you load the WSDL into PHP using file_get_contents($url)? Is it a PHP configuration setting that isn't allowing it to access it?

Comment: Yes I can load it from file_get_contents even also saw it in ie.

Comment: After such a long effort i came to this error :....INFO: Fault occurred!
org.codehaus.xfire.fault.XFireFault: Not enough message parts were received for the operation.

Answer (score 2):

One nice tool you could use is [wsdl2php-interpreter](http://code.google.com/p/wsdl2php-interpreter/), it will create classes etc four you.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code

```
 $Url = "http://localhost:8080/Indexer/services/IndexerService?wsdl";
    $params = array ("param1" =>"value","parm2"=>"value");

    $httpQuery = http_build_query ($params);
    $contextData = array (
                    "method" => "POST",
            "header" => "Connection: close\r\n".
                    "Content-Length: ".strlen($httpQuery)."\r\n",
                    "content"=> $httpQuery );               

    $context = stream_context_create (array ( "http" => $contextData )); 
    $result =  file_get_contents ($Url, false, $context);
```